# A Link to an script doesn't pass the arguments

Tags: php, linux, shell, arguments

I got the follwing setup.
I create a folder called tools and thats the treeview of it:

```
tools
|_ bin (folder)
|__ myscript (file)
|_ scripts (folder)
|__ myscript.php
```

so in the bin/myscript I put just this:

```
../scripts/myscript.php}
```

the file has permission to be executed (chmod +x)
and when I do

```
~$ sudo ./myscript -i
```

It's execute but the parameters are not pass to the script,
i get those with $argv[] if I run

```
sudo php scripts/myscript.php -i it works well.
```

Any idea of what could be happening here?

Comment: Remove the -i - it just prints out php info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$@` to your call in `myscript`, like this: `../scripts/myscript.php $@`

`$@` passes all the command line parameters the calling script had.

Reference: http://shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html